# Is it possible to change background of a website by using js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

So i need to change my website background dynamically from this class .
I'm not familliar with js so i want to ask for ur help.
Ty all.

```
<div class="text-center AnimeImage col-xl-3 col-md-6" id="AnimeImage">
<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/757324382426103878/799973669136629770/204129.png" alt="Enmusubi no Youko-chan" class="AnimeImg img-effect">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can but css is going to be a better route.

to do it with javascript you have to grab the class and give it a variable

`var bgDiv = document.getElementByClassName("yourClassName")`

then set it with styles

`bgDiv.styles.backgroundColor = "blue"`